# Jetpack Compose - mutableStateOf() not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I got a ScreenState data class in my ViewModel:

```
data class ScreenState(
    var isLoading: Boolean = true,
    val items: List<Posts> = emptyList()
)
```

and a mutableStateof:

```
private val _homeScreenState = mutableStateOf(ScreenState())
val homeScreenState: State<ScreenState> = _homeScreenState
```

Updating the isLoading property works fine, the change gets send to my UI:

```
_homeScreenState.value = _homeScreenState.value.copy(isLoading = true)
```

But updating an item inside my `List<Posts>` does not work.
Here is how I try to do it:

```
val updatedList = homeScreenState.value.items.toMutableList()
val index = updatedList.indexOfFirst { it.id == passedPost.id }
updatedList[index] = updatedList[index].copy(isLiked = true)
_homeScreenState.value = _homeScreenState.value.copy(items = updatedList)
```

I'm trying to update the isLiked Boolean inside my Post data class and show the change in the UI.
I do understand, that this is a normal behaviour and that the mutableStateOf does not update because the ScreenState itself does not update but the item inside the `List<Post>` of the ScreenState.

The problem is that I don't know how to trigger the UI to update.

**EDIT**
This is my Post Data Class:

```
data class Post(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String, 
    val description: String, 
    val isLiked: Boolean = false,
)
```

Comment: Is `Posts` a data class? Or, in general, does it have a proper `equals` implemented?

Comment: Can u try this; _homeScreenState.value = _homeScreenState.value.copy(
            items = _homeScreenState.value.items.toMutableList().also {
                it[index] = _homeScreenState.value.items[index].copy(isLike = true)
            }
        )

Comment: @gpunto its a data class, I updated my question with it

Comment: @commandiron unfortunately this does not work as well

Comment: I can't see an issue in the code you posted, so I guess it's somewhere else. How are you observing the state?

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Post(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val isLiked: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false),
)
```

or

```
class Post(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    isLiked: Boolean = false,
){

    val isLiked by mutableStateOf(isLiked)

}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still doesnt reflect the chagnes in the UI, its only updates on recomposition when I scroll down the list and then scrolll back up or when I switch to a new Screen

Comment: Update in State<T> propertie should trigger the UI to recompose